# How do you get a access token for postman?

Tags: oauth, access-token, postman

I am using postman to make request but instead of using my creditials I would like to use a token with OAuth 1.0.

I've looked up information about how to get a access token and im assuming the method is similar to what this article describes.

https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html#oauth-consumerkey

I just don't understand what they mean when I have to register my application. How do you go about doing that? In the following steps there seem's to be code writing involved in making the other request. How does that work? Please give me a more detailed explanation on how this process works.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you want to use an oauth or oauth2 system, you need tor register an application with the host system. What that means is that you go to yahoo for example, you create an application and they will give you a set of keys, a ClientID and a ClientSecret.

OAuth is about authenticating an application not individual users. Imagine you write a mobile app which needs to get its data from an API secured with OAuth2. The Api needs to only allow access to users coming from your app. So the app is the one that authenticates itself, not the actual user, if that makes sense. The APi doesn't care which user it is, it has no way of authenticating that user, but it can authenticate the application sending the request.

I've got a long article on how to create an entire oAuth2 system from scratch, with screenshots showing how to use it with postman. Even if you don't use dot net, the principles are similar and useful. Have a look and hopefully you can get what you need from it.

https://eidand.com/2015/03/28/authorization-system-with-owin-web-api-json-web-tokens/